# how to filter search by value in button text using jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How can i filter search by using value button here is my jquery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#myTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "text1",
            action: function(e, dt, node, config){
                dt.column(0).search("text1").draw();
            }
        },
        {
            text: "text2",
            action: function(e, dt, node, config){
                dt.column(0).search("text2").draw();
            }
        },
        {
            text: "text3",
            action: function(e, dt, node, config){
                dt.column(0).search("text3").draw();
            }
        }
    ]

})

});
</script>
```

I want to click button text1 and datatable will search text1 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action), the `dt` parameter should be an instance of the DataTable API, which has a [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) method.

So try the following:

```
dt.search('text1').draw()
```